# 2 databases locked, but only one can be successfully dumped (backed up do *.sql file) ... fail

Tags: replication, mysql

i have this situation

- 2 large databases on mysql server - srv1
- I need to transfer both to new server - srv2

so

- I use sql command "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;" to stop all modifications
- Then I use shell command "mysqldump --user=root --password=blaablaaa --databases shop1 shop2 > "e:\backup\dump_both.sql"
- I am completely stuck here because only SHOP1 database is dumped right and then file size stops growing and for long time nothing happens. Why - its exactly in a moment when second database should be dumped.

---

i have tried to unlock databases and then BOTH databases can be dumped perfectly, but while databases are locked only one can be dumped. Of coourse i need to lock them because of consistency. But why second database cannot be dumped in this situation ?

any ideas ?

note1: shop1 database uses only myisam tables, but shop2 mostly uses innodb.

Answer (score 0):

The FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK should be executed within the backup session.
Try to backup MyISAM tables with a --flush-logs and a --lock-all-tables options; and try to backup InnoDb tables with a --single-transaction option. More information in the documenation - [mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.hts.html).